# What is the ICAO equivalent of /G in a flight plan?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-planning, icao-sarps

How should I fill out an ICAO flight plan if I have a Garmin GNS-430W WAAS certified unit? I file as /G in the US domestic format.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I edited your question to make it - hopefully! - a little clearer but if I've got anything wrong you can always edit it yourself to correct it.

Answer (score 7):

I have a GNS-530W, which is identical to your unit except with a bigger screen and I file ICAO with a G, B, and S, which are GNSS/GPS, LPV, AND VOR/ILS, respectively, to indicate the equipment I have on board. Technically just the G would be sufficient but I list all I am capable of to assist ATC in routing me most effectively or in the event of an emergency.

This would be entered on the form as "G, B, S"

Here is an excellent article explaining the new fields and codes for filing ICAO as the FAA domestic flight plan form comes to an end soon:
[Filing ICAO Flight Plans in ForeFlight](https://blog.foreflight.com/2016/02/05/filing-icao-flight-plans-in-foreflight/)